# Gestionar el estado global de un proyecto en VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, eventos, aplicación-web, filereader, vanilla

Estoy haciendo una interfaz para cargar archivos en texto plano (en promedio 300 mb c/u) que se generan a través de un estándar de ing., esta interfaz tiene que permitir cargarlos y posteriormente unos algoritmos clasifican datos, finalmente, se envían a una API de la empresa que almacena el archivo en crudo y los datos filtrados. Acá les dejo un ejemplo simplificado basado en el código real:

```
const $fileElm = document.getElementById('file-input')
$fileElm.addEventListener('change', changeHandler)

function changeHandler (changed) {
  const readerObj = new FileReader()

  const file = changed.target.files[0]
  // ...
  const data = { file }

  readerObj.onload = () => handlerOnload(readerObj, data)
}

async function handlerOnload (reader, data) {
  // ...
  // filtrado de datos asincrono
  // ...

  sendDataToServer({ file, filteredData })
}
```

Como verán, todo el filtrado de datos lo hago en medio de un controlador de evento anidado en otro even handler. Esto es debido a que no se como separar esta lógica de clasificación, ya que esos datos los tengo disponibles solo en ese momento del tiempo, en ese momento de la ejecución de la aplicación.

**Mi duda es**, ¿Qué se les ocurre que podría hacer para gestionar el estado global de forma que si quiero seguir filtrando más información por separado y almacenarla convenientemente para trabajar con otras APIs y servicios en el futuro?

Y este es mi package json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@open-wc/building-rollup": "^2.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^14.1.0",
    "happy-dom": "^6.0.4",
    "rollup": "^2.79.1",
    "scss": "0.2.4",
    "standard": "17.0.0",
    "vite": "3.1.4",
    "vitest": "0.23.4"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "./node_modules/standard/eslintrc.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "web-ifc": "0.0.36"
  }
}
```